# Adobe After Effects - Script - How to move puppet pins relative to some other pin/layer anchor?

Tags: after-effects, script

I want to move some puppet pins relative to an anchor point.
Is there a simple script that does the math and makes the pin move with the anchor of a different layer?
This stuff seems pretty basic but I couldn't find any good scripts or explanations on how to do this efficiently.

Could someone please help with this?

Currently I have a very dumb solution, I just put a hidden shape layer over both the puppet pin and the layer I want the pin to move with. Then I parented the anchor point of this shape layer with the anchor point of the original layer, then I added a puppet pin onto the shape layer and parented the old puppet pin I want to move to the puppet pin on the shape layer.

Basically bridging the gap between the the pin and the original layer.